# Can I contribute to both a solo 401k and a regular 401k in the same year?

Tags: united-states, 401k, retirement-plan, solo-401k

I was self employed during the first quarter of 2011, then switched to full time employment.

I have a solo 401k that I haven't contributed to in tax year 2011.

I have been contributing to my employer's 401k (to capture the match).

Can I still make a contribution to my solo 401k, or is it disallowed because I participate in another plan?

If it is allowed, what limits are in effect for the combined contributions (solo + regular)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can contribute to both plans.

But note:

"Generally, all elective deferrals that you make to all plans in which you participate must be considered to determine if the dollar limits are exceeded."

The limit remains 16.5K whether you contribute to one, two, or more plans.

http://www.irs.gov/retirement/participant/article/0,,id=151786,00.html

Comment: What about the profit sharing contribution on the solo 401k? Is that unaffected by the contributions to my employer plan?

Comment: As profit-sharing is an "employer contribution" and not an "employee contribution", it should not affect the amount you as employee pay into your 401K(s). Regardless, I strongly recommend a check with your plan administrator to confirm/refute.